# How to stop the loop and add the value?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, sum, case

I have the following table:

```
id   tax    rate   quantity
 1   20     400       5
 2   20     566       2
 3   5      200       4
```

Here is my expected output:

```
 taxableamount   taxamount      total
    3132.00        626.40      3758.40
     800.00         40.00       840.00
```

Let me explain my attempts here:

If each row have the same tax value, I calculated the amount (`rate × quantity`) from each row of data and then calculate the tax amount `(amount × tax ÷ 100)` and displayed the result in a single row even if they come from multiple rows. But if the rows do not have same tax value, it will be displayed in separate rows.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(
          CASE WHEN tax=tax
          THEN rate*quantity ELSE 0 END) AS taxableamount,
          SUM(CASE WHEN tax=tax 
          THEN (rate*quantity)+(rate*quantity)*tax/100 ELSE 0 END) AS tax,
          SUM(CASE WHEN tax=tax 
          THEN (rate*quantity)*tax/100 ELSE 0 END) AS taxamount,
          SUM(CASE WHEN tax=tax 
          THEN (rate*quantity)+(rate*quantity)*tax/100 ELSE 0 END) AS total
          FROM pricing group by tax";
while($row = show($query)):
   echo '<td>'.$row->taxableamount.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row->taxamount.'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row->total.'</td>';
endwhile;
```

The above code gives me wrong and unexpected result. So looking at my expected output, how do I go about it. Please help.

Comment: Why do you use this code CASE WHEN tax=tax? tax is allways equal to tax

Comment: it's my attempt. I want to know when the tax value in each row is equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove your CASE statements. As i said in my comment, tax it´s allways equal to tax, because you are comparing with the same row. I have added the tax column, so you know the amounts for each kind of tax:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(rate * quantity) AS taxableamount,
    SUM(rate * quantity * tax / 100) AS taxamount,
    SUM(rate * quantity * (1 + tax) / 100) AS total,
    tax
FROM 
    pricing 
GROUP BY
    tax
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a `group by tax` in your sql statement. remove the remove case when. and two lines giving col called "tax"? that lokks like an error to me.

[group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[aggregation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Comment: my mistake, it should be taxamount.